# NullPointerException for layout.removeAllViews() in Android app

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

In my Android app I've got a layout from which I would like to remove all existent views (if any). So I do the following:

```
mySelector = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_my_selector);
// here is some other non related stuff
mySelector.removeAllViews();
```

So my first question: **I get a NullPointerException on the last line. I don't get what's the problem here. Does anybody know?**

After these lines I try to do this:

```
userSelector.addView(new RadioGroup(getActivity()));
```

But this unfortunately also results in a `NullPointerException`. Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: Is your View mySelector null ?

Comment: Debug the code and see if mySelector is Null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get null object from :

```
view.findViewById(R.id.layout_my_selector);
```

which probably means that it can't find a view.

Comment: You are right! The strange thing is that the name layout_my_selector does turn blue, like it can find it. How can it then not find it?

Comment: Inside object view there is no object referenced by "R.id.layout_my_selector". Check internal structure of a view in a debugger.

Comment: Awesome, I found it! It turned out that I didn't inflate a correct view, but one that's very similar.. Stupid. Thanks abunch!

Answer (score 2):

what is that "view" represents in your first line.is it initiated properly?
 then initiate mySelector properly..

and then try

> ```
> if(((LinearLayout) mySelector).getChildCount() > 0)
>
> ((LinearLayout) mySelector).removeAllViews();
> ```

Answer (score 1):

this means that mySelector var is null. check if you are referencing correct view